# Team Foundation 2015 Environment variable PATH not recognized

Tags: tfs, asp.net-core

I have a TFS 2015 build in which I want to run command 'dotnet restore'. On my build machine, the path to dotnet.exe is part of my environment variable 'Path'. When running the command from command prompt window, it works fine. When trying to run it via a TFS build step of type 'Command line' dotnet is not recognized. My path variable containing dotnet.exe path is at system level, so every users, including the one on which my build agent is running, should see it.

Comment: Can you run "cmd" as the TFS build account and confirm with `where dotnet`?

Comment: @DaveShaw     where dotnet in a cmd shell under as the TFS build account works, However, running the same command in a build step doesn't work. I also run cmd    whoami which gave me the correct user.

Comment: Are you starting a regular cmd shell or a developer cmd shell to test it? Also, can you add a Build Task to dump the environment variables to disk (maybe a PS1 script), that might enlighten you.

Comment: Did you restart the build service after adding the environment variable path?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested with TFS 2015.3, after adding dotnet.exe path in Environment Variables and add Command Line step in build definition, dotnet.exe can be recognized in the following setting. You may compare it with yours:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

FYI, this is still an issue with TFS 2017 as well. From my tests, it appears TFS doesn't like when the **PATH** variable is **over 900 characters**. After shortening the PATH variable and closing the dialog windows, restart the VSO/VSTS agent services and you should see the Path variable appear as a capability for the agent.    Hopefully this helps someone else.[image: Path]